# Auto suggest type of a state based on a property that is an array of strings in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm developing an open source library where we allow you to create a model instance for Laravel models from your front end in Cypress, allowing you to create true end-to-end tests.

Currently, I have a base builder class that has most of the heavy lifting:

```js
export class FactoryBuilder {
  ...
  
  protected possibleStates: string[] = [];
}
```

As you can see my model can have states. These states **need** to be defined in the backend and as such the developer can't insert a state that doesn't exist in the backend.

The developer will be able to extend this class by doing:

```js
export class UserFactoryBuilder extends FactoryBuilder { 
  protected possibleStates = ['inactive', 'blocked'];

  ...

  setStates(states) {
    this.factory.states = states;
    
    return this.factory;
  }
}
```

What I'm looking for is to tell the IDE that the `state` property can be auto-suggested values that are present in `possibleStates`. I have tried this so far:

```js
interface FactoryOptions {
  attributes: object;
  states: string[];
}

export class FactoryBuilder {  
  protected possibleStates: string[] = [];

  constructor(model: string, options: FactoryOptions & { states?: (typeof this.possibleStates[number])[] }) {
    ...
  }
}
```

But then I get the following errors from Typescript:

- `TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.`
- `TS4063: Parameter 'factoryOptions' of constructor from exported class has or is using private name 'this'.`

Any ideas on how I can allow autosuggestion on the `states` based on the values from the `possibleStates` array?

Comment: What `state` property?  Do you mean `states`?  Which property is that?  I see you reference `this.factory.states`.  What's `this.factory`?  Could you please modify this code to be a [mre] where the only problem present is the one you're running into?  Otherwise I have to spend time trying to recreate the issue instead of solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface FactoryOptions<T> {
    attributes: object;
    states: T[];
}

export class FactoryBuilder<T> {
    protected possibleStates: T[] = [];

    constructor(model: string, options: FactoryOptions<T>) {}
}

type States = "inactive" | "blocked";

export class UserFactoryBuilder extends FactoryBuilder<States> {
    protected possibleStates: States[] = ["inactive", "blocked"];

    constructor(model: string, options: FactoryOptions<States>) {
        super(model, options);
    }
}

const userFactory = new UserFactoryBuilder("hi", {
    // intellisense on "" in array
    states: ["blocked", "inactive"],
    attributes: {},
});
```

You can introduce generics and then specify in inheriting classes which types are allowed.